# applying function to every two columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

Is there a way to use the apply function to every two columns in a data frame?  If I have the data frame

```
dat <- data.frame(A=rnorm(100), B=rnorm(100),C=rnorm(100), D=rnorm(100))

A           B            C          D
0.1511642 -0.44930197  1.821832535  2.0145395
-1.1639599  0.42685832 -0.763015835 -0.7785278
0.8430158  0.26827386 -0.004560031  0.8823789
0.7103298  0.78512673 -0.968510541  0.5172418
0.8508458  0.05809655  0.391845531  0.7452540
0.2217195 -0.06988857  0.714890499 -1.1536502
```

and I want the sum of each column I can use

```
apply(dat,2,sum)
```

but what if i want to apply a function over every two columns?  For example

```
coefficients(lm(dat$A~dat$B))
coefficients(lm(dat$C~dat$D))
```

I have 400 columns and don't want to write this out 200 times for each pair of columns.  I thought a for loop using columns j and j+1 could work but I want the relationship between column A and B, then column C and D, then column E and F and so on.  Not column A and B, then column B and C, then C and D.  Is there a way to do this withe apply() or another function in the apply family?

Comment: Is there something in the names of the columns that state they should be paired? Or that one is X and the other Y? If so you can take advantage of that and make things a bit more clean.

Comment: Yeah, just using A,B,C.. was a quick example.  The actual data frame has columns paired by ID number.  So the first column is something like 1234.score1 and the second column is 1234..score2.  The third column would be 5678.score1 and the fourth 5678.score2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `mapply` / `Map` to repeat a function every two columns by subsetting your dataframe every two columns. Hope this helps!

**Using `lm`**

```
lm_list <- Map(function(y, x) summary(lm(y~x))$coefficients, dat[c(T,F)], dat[c(F,T)])
names(lm_list) <- paste0(names(dat[c(T,F)]), " ~ ", names(dat[c(F,T)]))
lm_list

$`A ~ B`
              Estimate Std. Error   t value  Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) 0.03566648  0.1051079 0.3393320 0.7350857
x           0.03602569  0.1162846 0.3098062 0.7573662

$`C ~ D`
                Estimate Std. Error     t value  Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) -0.008610382  0.1021835 -0.08426389 0.9330185
x           -0.053369101  0.1171255 -0.45565742 0.6496444
```

**Data**:

```
set.seed(42)
dat <- data.frame(A=rnorm(100), B=rnorm(100),C=rnorm(100), D=rnorm(100))
```

Comment: This definitely got me in the right direction!  How could I expand on this to also save a plot to a jpeg for each summary?   So using a function like function(x,y){mod <- lm(y~x)  jpeg('name.jpeg') plot(x,y) abline(mod)).  What would I put into the 'name.jpeg'?

Comment: Instead of bringing the jpeg into the function I ended up just using lapply over the list.  Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: Glad you figured it out on your own! That is how I would have approached it as well. Let me know if you have any other issues with it!

Answer (score 4):

Create a grouping vector `g`, split on it and lapply `lm` over it.

Note that if `d = data.frame(y, x)` for response `y` and predictor `x` then `lm(d)` is the regression `lm(y ~ x, d)` .

```
n <- ncol(dat)
g <- rep(1:n, each = 2, length = n) # 1 1 2 2 
L <- lapply(split.default(dat, g), lm)

sapply(L, coef) # coefficients
sapply(L, function(x) summary(x)$r.squared) # R^2
# etc.
```

It could also be done over the names:

```
L2 <- lapply(split.default(names(dat), g), function(nms) lm(dat[nms]))
sapply(L2, coef)
```

or if you want nicer Call: line in the output:

```
reg <- function(nms, dat) do.call("lm", list(reformulate(nms[2], nms[1]), quote(dat)))
L2 <- lapply(split.default(names(dat), g), reg, dat = dat)
sapply(L2, coef)
```

Note that variables in `lm` formulas cannot start with a digit so you may need to rename your columns if this requirement is violated.  If you use the lm(dat) form then this is not a requirement but if you use a formula it is.  See Note for examples.

### Note

Regarding the comment under the question about the form of the names if the names were as shown below we could alternately form g using this code:

```
# modify test example
s <- c("1234.score1", "1234.score2", "5678.score1", "5678.score2")
dat2 <- setNames(dat, s)

g <- cumsum(sub(".*\\D", "", names(dat2)) == 1)  # 1 1 2 2
L <- lapply(split.default(dat2, g), lm)
sapply(L, coef)
```

or we could use this (however, this will cause the output to be sorted by g):

```
# modify column names
dat3 <- dat2
names(dat3) <- paste0("x", names(dat3))

g <- sub("\\..*", "", names(dat3)) # x1234 x1234 x5678 x5678
reg <- function(nms, dat) do.call("lm", list(reformulate(nms[2], nms[1]), quote(dat)))
L2 <- lapply(split.default(names(dat3), g), reg, dat = dat3)
sapply(L2, coef)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of the naming convention to first stack the data and then operate on the groups of common IDs. This may make things easier for future analysis.

I modified the column names per the comment.

```
dat <- data.frame(ID1.score1=rnorm(100), ID1.score2=rnorm(100),ID2.score1=rnorm(100), ID2.score2=rnorm(100))

library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)
```

Split the column names at ".". The first half are the IDS, the second half specify the score1 or score2 (i.e., X or Y).

```
cols <- str_split(names(dat), "\\.", simplify = TRUE)
ids <- unique(cols[,1])
scores <- unique(cols[,2])
```

Using `purrr`, iterate through the IDs and select the column pair that starts with that. Add another column to this new data.frame to store the ID. Then stack all of these by rows. Now we have a "tidy" formatted dataset.

```
stacked_dat <- ids %>%
  map_dfr(~ {
    select(dat, starts_with(.)) %>%
      set_names(scores) %>%
      mutate(id = .x)})
```

Now just group on the ID column and fit the model for each ID.

```
fits <- stacked_dat %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  do(model = lm(score1 ~ score2, data = .))
```

Get the model statistics like this in a list. The package `broom` might help stack and clean things up, with the help of `purrr`.

```
fits$model
```

Answer (score 0):

This is something completely different. You can create a list of formulas for each pairing based on the names. Then just iterate over each formula on the same data set.

```
dat <- data.frame(ID1.score1=rnorm(100), ID1.score2=rnorm(100),ID2.score1=rnorm(100), ID2.score2=rnorm(100))

ids <- unique(sub("\\..*", "", names(dat)))
f <- lapply(paste0(ids, ".score2 ~ ", ids, ".score1"), as.formula)

models <- lapply(f, function(f) lm(f, dat))
```

Then you can just extract or do what you want with the list of models.

```
model_coef <- sapply(models, coef)
colnames(model_coef) <- ids

model_coef

                    ID1         ID2
(Intercept) -0.07592376 -0.02472962
ID1.score1  -0.02284805  0.09144416
```